pgadmin4 error when restoring database from tar file (PostgreSQL 16)
Screenshot of what pgadmin shows me
I´m trying to load a tar file usinf pgAdmin 4 (PostgreSQL16) on my Mac, but it´s failing and all I get is "Process failed" as shown on the screenshot, but doesn´t show me what kind of error might be! I´m not sure what to do and the information I hace found on internet is not helping me! Does anyone has an idea what to do?
